# BeanCreationException error happend on spring when I try to seperate the springMVC context with the root context bean scan

Tags: spring-mvc

I define two spring context files for my application,  springmvc-config.xml for the springMVC and han-config.xml for the root Application Context.
What I want to do is to use springmvc-config.xml to scan all the @Controller beans and han-config.xml to scan all the @Component, @Repository, and @Service beans

```
My problem is if I use the <context:component-scan base-package="com.leo.han" / > in the springmvc-config.xml the application will run perfectly and no errors during the deployment.

But if I want to use 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.leo.han.controllers" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
in the springmvc-config.xml to only scan the controllers and  use
<context:component-scan base-package="com.leo.han" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
in the han-config.xml to only scan for the @Component, @Repository, and @Service beans which is a recommended approach in the spring forum.

I will get terrible errors like 

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.leo.han.services.UserService com.leo.han.controllers.LoginController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.leo.han.services.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}


it seems like the userService  bean is never created for some reason 


Can anyone help me on this 



My package structure is:


com.leo.han.controllers  (all controllers annotated with @Controller)
com.leo.han.services  (all service  annotated with @Service)
com.leo.han.dao (all das annotated with @Repository)


Here is a sample code 

    @Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showLogin() {

            return "login";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/newaccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String newAccountPost(Model model, User user) throws Exception {


            user.setEnabled(true);
            user.setAuthority("APP_VIEW");
            userService.addUser(user);

            return "accountcreated";
        }

    }

    @Service("userService")
    public class UserService {

        @Autowired
        private UserDao userDao;

        public List<User> getAllUsers() {

            return userDao.searchAll();

        }

        public void addUser(User user) {

            userDao.createUser(user);
        }

        public boolean isUserExist(User user) {

            return userDao.isUserExist(user);
        }

    }



My web.xml




    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/config/han-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
        <filter>
            <display-name>springSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>



My springmvc-config.xml (springMVC context config file)





    <context:component-scan base-package="com.leo.han.controllers" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

        <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/jsps/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
            <property name="order" value="1"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="viewTileResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
            <property name="order" value="0"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
            id="tilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layout.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/message" />
            <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="localeResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
            <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"></property>
        </bean>
        <mvc:interceptors>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="language"></property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptors>


my han-config.xml  (my root applicationContext file)




    <context:component-scan base-package="com.leo.han"
            use-default-filters="false">
            <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
        </context:component-scan>



        <import resource="persistence-config.xml" />
        <import resource="security-config.xml" />

Please help, I have already search around here for two days in order to find a solution to my case, however all the solution seems to not work for my case.

Thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using similar configuration but the base package is same "a.b" in both cases and one contains exclusion for Controllers ( for root context) and other consists of inclusion ( for mvc context) and it works fine. You can try that.

Now you'd love Spring for this  - If you want to programmatically determine the candidate beans in the classpath with your base package, you can write a simple test program like below which will list the candidate components.

```
public class TestComponentScanner {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider =
                new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
                String basePackage = "com/leo";
                provider.addExcludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Controller.class, true));
                Set<BeanDefinition> filteredComponents = provider.findCandidateComponents(basePackage);
                System.out.println("No of components :"+filteredComponents.size());

                for (BeanDefinition component : filteredComponents) {
                System.out.println("Component:"+ component.getBeanClassName());
                }

                provider.resetFilters(true);
                provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Controller.class, true));
                filteredComponents = provider.findCandidateComponents(basePackage);
                System.out.println("No of components :"+filteredComponents.size());

                for (BeanDefinition component : filteredComponents) {
                System.out.println("Component:"+ component.getBeanClassName());
                }



    }
```